# Select Top 50 from on V class based on a value from a different class

Tags: orientdb

I'm doing a proof of concept.  I have a "ArticleRead" V class with a not unique property "JournalTitle" (lots of reads from each journal), a "Product" V class with a not unique property of "Subject", and an edge between them with a property called "type".

ArticleRead has a vertex inserted for every article read by a user of our system.

Can anyone give an approximate SQL to find the Top 50 read journal titles from a specific subject?  In our current RDBMS, we have to find the products with that subject, then count up all the articleReads by journalTitle of those products, and then get the top 50.  It takes several lifetimes.

Also, any suggestions on the modifications to the edge or whatever are welcome (this is a proof of concept that we are playing with after very minimal self-training).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 SELECT FROM ( 
   SELECT JournalTitle, count(*) as count FROM (
     SELECT expand(out()) FROM Product WHERE Subject = ?
   ) GROUP BY JournalTitle
 ) ORDER BY count LIMIT 50
```

or

```
SELECT FROM (
   SELECT JournalTitle, count(*) as count
   FROM ArticleRead
   WHERE in()[0].Subject = ?
) ORDER BY count LIMIT 50
```

Just for the record, for operations like this (a single level traversal and an aggregation) the advantages of a graph database compared to a relational db are typically not substantial

Comment: Thanks.  the "real" data would have a child of product for the subject, more classes with edges to the articlesread, and terabytes of articlereads. The sheer size of the articlesreads makes us throw away older data in Oracle each year.  I'm hoping document/graph databases prove to be a better solution.  I'm having some trouble with this but I think i have my edge backwards (out would be the productID in my edge) and I think I corrupted it trying to rename the "in" and "out".

Comment: Slight tweak -
  GROUP BY JournalTitle
  ORDER BY COUNT LIMIT 50